# Nesting of EL expressions when creating own tag

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, taglib

I'm using JSF 2.0 and creating my own tag. The result I'd like to have is a label which I can use like this:

```
<mytaglib:label attr="test" />
```

which would render an `<h:outputLabel />` like this:

```
<h:outputLabel id="test" value="#{textBean.label['test']}" />
```

TextBean has the property `label` (of type `Map<String, String>`), which delivers me a text for each key.

My label.xhtml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:outputLabel for="#{attr}" value="#{textBean.label['#{attr}']}:" 
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Boxing `#{attr}` within `#{textBean.label['#{attr}']}` doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to get this to work, or which workaround could I make to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use nested EL-expressions.

Try something like this instead:

```
value="#{textBean.label[attr]}"
```

I'm however not completely sure if this is the fully correct syntax, since I don't know what `label` from `textBean` represents. In case you need more information, please provide a sample of `textBean`.

Comment: That works, thank you! I added a more precise description of `label` to the question.